# Is there a way I can initiate a empty array, and add elements to it in a loop?

Tags: praat

e.g in python:

```
array = []

for num in range(1, 11):
    array.append(num)
```

I've looked at the praat documentation (https://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Scripting_5_6__Arrays_and_dictionaries.html), but can't make it work!